# angular-chart error on line chart: unable to parse color

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, chart.js, linechart

I tried to create a bar chart and everything works fine. But when i create a line chart the following error is thrown:

**Uncaught Error: Unable to parse color from object ["rgba(167,199,230,1)","rgba(61,53,189,1)","rgba(120,87,48,1)","rgba(110,93,105,1)","rgba(112,33,221,1)","rgba(136,6,10,1)","rgba(154,2..**

I only have these options to set the color and the line chart itself:

```
 ChartJsProvider.setOptions({
    chartColors: ['#a7c7e6', '#4f8fcd', '#37648f', '#C7C7C7', '#2f557b', '#748ba1', '#536373', '#bfbdb6'],
    responsive: true
});

ChartJsProvider.setOptions('line', {
    showLines: true,
    fill: false
});
```

Somehow even the "fill: false" is not working, and when i hover over the points the error shown below is thrown.. 
My canvas looks like this:

```
<canvas class="chart chart-line" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-options="options"></canvas>
```

I have no idea what i did wrong and somehow i found nothing on the internet that could solve my problem.. maybe someone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Okay.. it was because i didnt set any series tags.. somehow that was the reason the diagrams didnt work

Comment: `Okay.. it was because i didnt set any series tags`. What does that mean. Please improve your answer with the code to help others to come.